# Apps not looking same when i run them in actual device

Tags: android

I am new to android programming but I know how everything works, recently I was trying to create an app just like uber after I finished creating the launch activity i tested it on my actual device just to check whether everything looks fine but when I launched it on my device everything (layouts, imageViews, Textviews..etc) were misplaced, I have never had this problem before its just this time. could anyone please tell me where am I going wrong? 
I am attaching screenshots below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="com.example.keyur.uber.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/showtext"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:text="@string/get_moving_with_uber"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:typeface="monospace" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgv"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/showtext"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/india"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/countrycode"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgv"
                android:text="@string/_91"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"

                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:fontFamily="monospace"
                android:hint="@string/enter_your_mobile_number"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHint="#484848"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:inputType="number"

                />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layoutbg" />




        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

screenshots-
this is what the app looks on pixel 4 as it is set on default. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFvRm.png)

this is what it looks when I switch it to pixel xl, everything gets messed up

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SeES.png)

Comment: may be it's due to constrain problem.

Comment: Maybe post your code.

Comment: added the xml code

Comment: I think it's because you used only pixel values. You should use *match_parent* or *wrap_content* as much as you can for defining *layout_width* and *layout_height*.

Comment: but even the imageviews and textviews are out of place. for example the flag logo imageview is out of place in pixel xl's screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Due do you are fixing the layout **hight** an **width** so each and very device have different screen size. You should use `match_parent` and `wrap_content`. If you want to split all device space in the same manner, you have to use **weight**.

> **How to use weight [reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)**

Answer (score 0):

> Either you can go for **"Weight Sum"**, or you should set your
>   `TextView` for country-code **"layout_toRightOf"** to image view
>   instead of **"layout_toEndOf"**.